# Nested Gridview in Repeater control

Tags: asp.net, gridview, nested, repeater

I have a gridview control nested within a repeater control.

---

The repeater control is databound on pageload and in the itemdatabound event
I look for the gridview control

If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
    Dim gvw As GridView = DirectCast(e.Item.Controls(3), GridView)
    gvw.DataSource = GetData()
    gvw.DataBind()
End If

After all this happens my page is displaying the repeater controls data
and data in the gridview but the problem is only alternate gridviews have data
i.e. row 1, 3, 5... in repeater control has grid that is databound
but rows 2, 4, 6... does not display data

markup is - just an example

`<repeater>`
`<itemtemplate>`
`<table>`
`<tr>`
`<td>`
`<gridview />`
`</td>`
`</tr>`
`<tr>`
`<td>`
`<label Text='<%# Eval("some_data") %>'`
`</td>`
`</tr>`
`</table>`
`</itemtemplate>`
`</repeater>`

again the above markup is just an example and it is complete

I think I'm doing something seriously wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then Dim gvw As GridView = DirectCast(e.Item.Controls(3), GridView) gvw.DataSource = GetData() gvw.DataBind() End If
```

you should add an "OR" clause to check if the ItemType is an AlternateItem as well

```
If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OR e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternateItem Then Dim gvw As GridView = DirectCast(e.Item.Controls(3), GridView) gvw.DataSource = GetData() gvw.DataBind() End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much... you rock
I'm really foolish to ignore the alternate item fact
thanks a ton

Comment: Sometimes the worst mistakes are the easiest to fix. That's why a second pair of eyes always helps! Cheers!